# Android - Multiple Response Types in Moshi

Tags: android, json, moshi

I can get the following JSON data from the server :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "groupName": "MyBestFriends"
}
```

In my Android project, I use `Moshi` to handle this response. Particularly, I use the following data class for that type of response:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Group(
    val id: Long,
    val groupName:String
)
```

So, but in case a requested Group does not exist, then I can also get the following JSON response:

```
{
    "detail": "Not found."
}
```

How, could my Group data class also handle this ? What I want is handling both types of responses but with only one data class ? Is that possible ?

Note:
When I used Java and GSON in my earlier Android Projects, I could use the `@SerializedName` annotation for the fields and whatever JSON response came in the GSON adapter mapped that to the given class. So, in my case it would be something like this:

```
public class Group {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private Long id;

    @SerializedName("groupName")
    private String groupName;

    @SerializedName("detail")
    private String detail;

    // getter & setter
}
```

Is this also possible with Moshi ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can use `@Json(name="detail")` on your field to assign it a name when encoding and decoding.